# Pycharm Run/Debug Configuration saved as default

Tags: python, pycharm

Simple question but couldn't find a clear answer anywhere. Do i have to create a new run/debug configuration every time i create a new project, and assign the .py file at "script" or is there a way to make pycharm do this automatically. Would love to know! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create new run/debug configuration in every new project based on pre-defined templates.

However you can `edit a template` so that some of the **values will be set by default**.

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/changing-run-debug-configuration-defaults.html) is the information on how to change defaults.

You can also use [temporary run/debug configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-saving-temporary-run-debug-configurations.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can run a .py file directly without manually creating a Run/Debug Configuration. To do so, right click on the file in the Project view and select either the Run or Debug option from the context menu.