# How to save a test run config as default in Pycharm?

Tags: configuration, pycharm, default, testrunconfig

Currently for any test run, I have to keep adding the options `--keepdb -v2` to the testrun configuration as below snapshot

[image]

How to save this as default for next test run?

p.s.

The [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=pycharm%20-%20how%20save%20test%20run%20config%20as%20default%3F&newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&sxsrf=ALeKk00iTWIUy9RE0omVCFseDRqRjBDquQ:1606724540683&ei=vKvEX46hKZGbmgeZxqcg&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiO7_6r66ntAhWRjeYKHRnjCQQQ8NMDegQIDRBH&biw=1533&bih=732) leads to limitted helpful post [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206245939-How-can-I-set-defaults-for-test-configurations-).

[Search on our stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How%20to%20save%20a%20test%20run%20config%20as%20default%20in%20Pycharm%3F&searchOn=3) site results 0 result; related suggestion leads us to [this closer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46962936/248616) post.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397063)? But basically, save the configuration. Those greyed out tests are generally the result of your test suite keeping a temporary configuration.

Comment: @bad_coder Not sure what you are talking about...

Comment: @NamGVU Please try to update the template under Templates directory (under the last `Test:...` configuration on your screenshot)

Comment: @user2235698 I see. Updating the Template working for me. Please post it as an answer to get accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to update the template under `Templates` directory (under the last `Test:...` configuration on your screenshot)

Comment: Thank you! That's what I'm looking for!

Comment: This only work for current opened project. How to set it pycharm-wise aka ide-wise i.e. running new test in other project will share same modified template. Any hint is appreciated!